# How to select a solution from NSolve with specific characteristics?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to establish a way in which I can select the type of solutions obtained from NSolve. Let's put it into an example: Having this equation `x^3 + 10 x^2 + 169 x == 0`, find its solutions.

```
NSolve[x^3 + 10 x^2 + 169 x == 0, x]

(* Out: 
{{x -> -5. - 12. I}, {x -> -5. + 12. I}, {x -> 0. + 0. I}}
*)
```

Now, if I select the solutions containing a real part AND imaginary part lower than zero, I have:

```
NSolve[x^3 + 10 x^2 + 169 x == 0 && ReIm[x] < 0, x]

(* Out: {{x -> -5. - 12. I}}
```

Until here, there is no problem. However, **how can I select the solutions containing a real part OR an imaginary part greater than zero**?

Comment: `NSolve[x^3 + 10 x^2 + 169 x == 0 && (Im[x] > 0 || Re[x] > 0), x]`

Comment: `NSolve[x^3 + 10 x^2 + 169 x == 0 && Abs[x] != 0, x]`